# How to get list out of string represented as ["Smth", "Smth", "Smth"]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have an pandas series object that includes features related to house. Those features are placed in squared brackets like this : ['Laundry In Unit', 'No Fee', 'Elevator'] but I need to have these features as a list of strings so I wonder if it possible.

Actually I want to create new column that will have "feature score" so I add points for different features. I tried to implement it like this(code below text) but this "feature" column appeared to have not lists but strings that look like lists.

```
features_dict = {
    'Laundry In Unit,':5 ,
    'No Fee,':5,
    'Elevator,': 3,
    'Dogs Allowed,':3,
    'Cats Allowed,': 3,
    'Swimming Pool,': 8,
    'Doorman,':9,
    'Fitness Center,': 8,
    'Dishwasher,': 5,
    'Hardwood Floors,': 4,
    'Pre-War,': 3,
    'Common Outdoor Space,': 4,
    'Private Outdoor Space,':8
}
features_list = clean_data['features'].tolist()
features_score = [0] * len(features_list)
for i in range(len(features_list)):
  for key, num in features_dict.items():
    for word in features_list[i].split(" "):
      if key == word:
        features_score[i]+=num
```

Comment: What is `clean_data`? `for i in range(len(lst)): lst[i]` is an extremely stupid idea to loop through the elements of lists, you should just iterate over the list directly like this: `for e in lst: e`, and your nested loops are ugly and I don't think you know what you are doing...

Comment: `import ast; ast.literal_eval('''["Smth", "Smth", "Smth"]''')` => `['Smth', 'Smth', 'Smth']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a string that `repr`s like this:

`'["Smth", "Smth", "Smth"]'`

and you want a list that looks like this:

`["Smth", "Smth", "Smth"]`

then you need `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import ast

the_string = '["Smth", "Smth", "Smth"]'

the_list = ast.literal_eval(the_string)
print(the_list)
```

output:

```
['Smth', 'Smth', 'Smth']
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe `features_dict.keys()` u will have a list of the key

Have a nice day

Comment: But I need the values too, not onlu keys, don't I?

Comment: It's what I understand from your post "but I need to have these features as a list of strings so I wonder if it possible."